# MySQL / Entity Framework / MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I seem to be having issues when using MySQL to connect to an existing DB. I am using Entity Framework and using it to read from a current Database.

When I go and visit a page to load info up, I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

My `web.config`:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory
          type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                  type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
             invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" 
             type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Help appreciated in advance

Comment: I would try these steps first: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html